# hibernate sql join query error : javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee

i want to get data from 2 tables using a sql join query, but i get this error 
i don't know how to fix it, if you have any idea. i'll appreciate your help.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "annee"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:151)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:64)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditorRenderer.encodeEnd(CellEditorRenderer.java:38)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:823)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:784)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:699)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:654)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:249)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:211)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

index.xhtml

```
 <h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="listeBudgets" value="#{budgetisationBean.listeBudgets}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <f:facet name="header">
           Budgetisation
        </f:facet>

       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowEdit}" />
       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowCancel}"/>

        <p:column headerText="Annee">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeBudgets.annee.annee}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeBudgets.annee.annee}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Id rubrique">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeBudgets.rubrique.libelleRubrique}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeBudgets.rubrique.libelleRubrique}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Crédit ouvert">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeBudgets.creditOuvert}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeBudgets.creditOuvert}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Crédit reporté ">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeBudgets.creditReporte}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeBudgets.creditReporte}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
       <p:column style="width:32px" headerText="Modification">
           <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>


</h:form>
```

BudgetisationHibernateDao.java

```
@Repository
public class BudgetisationHibernateDao implements BudgetisationDao{
    private List<Budgetisation> listeBudgets;
    private Budgetisation budget;
    @Override
    public List<Budgetisation> getAllBudgets() {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("select b.annee, r.libelleRubrique, b.creditOuvert, b.creditReporte from Rubrique r, Budgetisation b where r.idRubrique = b.rubrique");
            listeBudgets = q.list();
            return listeBudgets;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Budgetisation.java

```
package net.vo;

public class Budgetisation  implements java.io.Serializable {


    private BudgetisationId id;
    private Rubrique rubrique;
    private Annee annee;
    private Double creditOuvert;
    private Double modification;
    private Double creditReporte;

    public Budgetisation() {
    }


    public Budgetisation(BudgetisationId id, Rubrique rubrique, Annee annee) {
        this.id = id;
        this.rubrique = rubrique;
        this.annee = annee;
    }
    public Budgetisation(BudgetisationId id,Double creditOuvert, Double modification, Double creditReporte) {
       this.id = id;
       this.creditOuvert = creditOuvert;
       this.modification = modification;
       this.creditReporte = creditReporte;
    }
    public Budgetisation(BudgetisationId id,Rubrique rubrique, Annee annee,Double creditOuvert, Double modification, Double creditReporte) {
       this.id = id;
       this.annee = annee;
       this.rubrique = rubrique;
       this.creditOuvert = creditOuvert;
       this.modification = modification;
       this.creditReporte = creditReporte;
    }

    public BudgetisationId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(BudgetisationId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Rubrique getRubrique() {
        return this.rubrique;
    }

    public void setRubrique(Rubrique rubrique) {
        this.rubrique = rubrique;
    }
    public Annee getAnnee() {
        return this.annee;
    }

    public void setAnnee(Annee annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }
    public Double getCreditOuvert() {
        return this.creditOuvert;
    }

    public void setCreditOuvert(Double creditOuvert) {
        this.creditOuvert = creditOuvert;
    }
    public Double getModification() {
        return this.modification;
    }

    public void setModification(Double modification) {
        this.modification = modification;
    }
    public Double getCreditReporte() {
        return this.creditReporte;
    }

    public void setCreditReporte(Double creditReporte) {
        this.creditReporte = creditReporte;
    }




}
```

Budgetisation.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 19 mai 2014 19:57:08 by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="net.vo.Budgetisation" table="budgetisation" catalog="pfa">
      <composite-id name="id" class="net.vo.BudgetisationId">
            <key-property name="idRubrique" type="int">
                <column name="idRubrique" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="annee" type="int">
                <column name="annee" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="rubrique" class="net.vo.Rubrique" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="idRubrique" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="annee" class="net.vo.Annee" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="annee" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="creditOuvert" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="creditOuvert" precision="8" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="modification" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="modification" precision="8" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="creditReporte" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="creditReporte" precision="8" scale="0" />
        </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

BudgetisationId.java

```
package net.vo;

public class BudgetisationId  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int idRubrique;
     private int annee;

    public BudgetisationId() {
    }

    public BudgetisationId(int idRubrique, int annee) {
       this.idRubrique = idRubrique;
       this.annee = annee;
    }

    public int getIdRubrique() {
        return this.idRubrique;
    }

    public void setIdRubrique(int idRubrique) {
        this.idRubrique = idRubrique;
    }
    public int getAnnee() {
        return this.annee;
    }

    public void setAnnee(int annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }


   public boolean equals(Object other) {
         if ( (this == other ) ) return true;
         if ( (other == null ) ) return false;
         if ( !(other instanceof BudgetisationId) ) return false;
         BudgetisationId castOther = ( BudgetisationId ) other; 

         return (this.getIdRubrique()==castOther.getIdRubrique())
 && (this.getAnnee()==castOther.getAnnee());
   }

   public int hashCode() {
         int result = 17;

         result = 37 * result + this.getIdRubrique();
         result = 37 * result + this.getAnnee();
         return result;
   }   


}
```

BudgetisationBean.java

```
package controller;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import model.services.BudgetisationMetier;
import net.vo.Annee;
import net.vo.Budgetisation;
import net.vo.BudgetisationId;
import net.vo.Rubrique;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("view")
public class BudgetisationBean implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Autowired
    private BudgetisationMetier budgetisationMetier;

    private List<Object> listeBudgets;
    private BudgetisationId id;
    private Rubrique rubrique;
    private Annee annee;
    private Double creditOuvert;
    private Double modification;
    private Double creditReporte;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listeBudgets = budgetisationMetier.getAllBudgets();
    }

     public List<Object> getListeBudgets() {
        return listeBudgets;
    }
    public void insert()
    {
        Budgetisation budget = new Budgetisation();
    budgetisationMetier.insert(budget);
    }
    public void update()
    {
        Budgetisation budget = budgetisationMetier.getBudget(this.id);
    budgetisationMetier.update(budget);
    }

    public BudgetisationMetier getBudgetisationMetier() {
        return budgetisationMetier;
    }

    public void setBudgetisationMetier(BudgetisationMetier budgetisationMetier) {
        this.budgetisationMetier = budgetisationMetier;
    }

  /*  public void setListeBudgets(List<Budgetisation> listeBudgets) {
        this.listeBudgets = listeBudgets;
    }
*/
    public BudgetisationId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BudgetisationId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Rubrique getRubrique() {
        return rubrique;
    }

    public void setRubrique(Rubrique rubrique) {
        this.rubrique = rubrique;
    }

    public Annee getAnnee() {
        return annee;
    }

    public void setAnnee(Annee annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }

    public Double getCreditOuvert() {
        return creditOuvert;
    }

    public void setCreditOuvert(Double creditOuvert) {
        this.creditOuvert = creditOuvert;
    }

    public Double getModification() {
        return modification;
    }

    public void setModification(Double modification) {
        this.modification = modification;
    }

    public Double getCreditReporte() {
        return creditReporte;
    }

    public void setCreditReporte(Double creditReporte) {
        this.creditReporte = creditReporte;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you had the list type listeBudgets, And the object class that contain this?

Answer (score 0):

You will be needing a bean like:

```
class Budget {
    private Integer annee;
    private Integer libelleRubrique;
    private Integer creditOuvert;
    private Integer creditReporte;

    //generate public getters and setters for the above fields
}
```

Then the return type of method getAllBudgets() needs to be List<Budget> rather than List

And your query should be like:

```
"select b.annee as \"annee\", r.libelleRubrique as \"libelleRubrique\", b.creditOuvert as \"creditOuvert\", b.creditReporte as \"creditReporte\" from Rubrique r, Budgetisation b where r.idRubrique = b.rubrique"
```

Finally instead of using:

```
listeBudgets = q.list();
return listeBudgets;
```

you would need to use following:

```
return q.setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.Transformers.aliasToBean(Budget.class)).list();
```

Comment: i think i can't use in my hibernate implementation a managed bean like in List<Budget> what i was using is a class POJO. i will edit my request what i'm really using @Kaushik Shrestha

Comment: The transformer is the right approach, but you should use `Budgetisation` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need join.. Hibernate should know to unify entities.
As much as i can see you can do something like that in the query

```
"Select * From Budgetisation b";
```

I used Hibernate annotation so i am not sure about the syntax but you need to refer the relation to Rubrique in the cfg file. Hibernate should join it for you

The query will retunr list of Budgetisation 
And you can get the Rubrique  by: budInstace.getRubrique() after the query will return result.

Could you try this?

Comment: i didn't understand how i can get the rubrique and where i'm going to call this method